# Вопрос о __proto__

Tags: javascript

Всем доброго утра! Продолжаю разбирать код который генерирует babel. Приведу пример...

```
class Animal{ }
class Rabbit extends Animal{}
```

Такой код после транспилирования сгенеририрует функцию `_inherits`, в которой
будут присутствовать инструкции:

```
 subClass.prototype = Object.create(superClass && superClass.prototype, {
    constructor: {
        value: subClass,
        enumerable: false,
        writable: true,
        configurable: true
    }
});
if (superClass) Object.setPrototypeOf ? Object.setPrototypeOf(subClass, superClass) : subClass.__proto__ = superClass;
```

Не могу понять зачем в последней инструкции устанавливается `subClass.__proto__` в `superClass`, если при создании объекта туда будет установлен `subClass.prototype`?

Answer (score 1):

Оказалось, что первая инструкция копирует только свойства прототипа(что логично и понятно мне). Но мне и в голову не приходило что с помощью второй инструкции можно скопировать статические свойства одного объекта в другой.
Кому интересно, ответ здесь: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52793807/function-inherits-babel-after-transpiling